# Google analytics api , get list account - gapi.client.analytics.management is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I added this line of code to my working code

```
// Do the magic const  
request = gapi.client.analytics.management.accountSummaries.list();
  request.execute(handleResponse)
```

and Get this error, why 'management' is undefined? what do I need to change?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'management' of undefined
    at queryReports
```

All code :

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="client_id">
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
</head>
<body>

<!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
<p class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></p>


<script>
  // Replace with your view ID.
  var VIEW_ID = 'ga:104831427';

let userEmail ; 
let userId;
let fullName;
let firstName;
let lastName;
let idToken;
let request;


  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
  function queryReports(googleUser) {



 var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

userId = profile.getId();

fullName = profile.getName();

firstName = profile.getGivenName();

lastName = profile.getFamilyName();

userEmail = profile.getEmail();

idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

// Do the magic const  
request = gapi.client.analytics.management.accountSummaries.list();
  request.execute(handleResponse)



 




    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
       "metrics": [
          {
            "expression": "ga:sessions"
          }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
            { "name": "ga:date" }
        ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

 function displayResults(response) {
   
var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);


window.parent.postMessage({formattedJson:(formattedJson),userEmail:(userEmail),userId:(userId),fullName:(fullName),firstName:(firstName),lastName:(lastName),idToken:(idToken),request:(request)}, "https://www.mywebsite.com"); 
  }



</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you following this ? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js

Comment: I try this code but for some reason, it doesn't work I just need to get the account list, why management is undefined? gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then(handleAccounts);

Comment: probably has something to do with the fact that you are missing all of the authorization code so client hasnt been set up properly.

Comment: But this function is working gapi.client.request

Comment: The javascript client dynamically builds the library based on the discovery docs. I think you are missing "gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {....});"